# Casting a component with vue typescript - accessing child methods

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typescript-decorator, vue-class-components

I am trying to access a child component method. Usually this is fine

```
 this.$refs.searchInput.reset()
```

To keep typescript happy this is required.

```
(this.$refs.searchInput as HTMLFormElement).reset()
```

I am not overly keen on the syntax. Is there no way to cast in the component options

```
export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'UserForm',
  components: {
       SearchInput as HTMLFORMELEMENT
    }
```

Should I use the class/decorator syntax for this to make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official way to declare the type for `$refs` in component options.

Indeed it seems you can avoid the type assertion by using either [`vue-class-component`](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/refs-type-extension.html):

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component
export default class UserForm extends Vue {
  $refs!: {
    searchInput: HTMLFormElement
  }

  mounted() {
    this.$refs.searchInput.reset()
  }
}
```

or [`vue-property-decorator`](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator#Ref):

```js
import { Vue, Component, Ref } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class UserForm extends Vue {
  @Ref() readonly searchInput!: HTMLFormElement

  mounted() {
    this.searchInput.reset()
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the Composition API, declaring the type for the [template `ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html):

```js
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from 'vue' // or `@vue/composition-api` for Vue 2

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const searchInput = ref<HTMLFormElement>()

    onMounted(() => searchInput.value?.reset())

    return { searchInput }
  }
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-typing-template-ref?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyForm.vue)